# Regular Expression - Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to get the a sub string from a string using regular expression but it getting error as my regular expression is not working. Can any one help me out in writing correct one :

Here is the Pattern on which i am trying to write the regular expression :

```
MSM8_BD_V4.3_1-1_idle-Kr_Run3.xlsx
MSM8_BD_V4.3_2-6_mp3-Kr_Run2.xlsx
MSM8_BD_V4.3_Camera_snap-7.xlsx
MSM8_BD_V4.3_Camera_snap-8.xlsx
MSM8_BD_V4.3_Radio_202.16-0.xlsx
```

**I am trying to get the bold part of the substring** .

below is the Regular expression i tried:

```
my $line = "MSM8939_BD_V4.3_1-1_idle-Kratos_Run3.xlsx";
my ($captured) = $line =~ /MSM8939_BD_V4\.\3\_[d]*(.+?)\w/gx;
print "$captured\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[d]` matches nothing but the literal letter `d`.  You want `\d`, without the brackets, to match a digit.  However, it looks like you also want to include underscores. That would be `[\d_]`.

Try this:

```
/^MSM8_BD_V4\.3_[\d_]*-?([^-]+)/
```

If I run this on your input (with e.g. `perl -nE 'say $1 if /^MSM8_BD_V4\.3_[\d_]*-?([^-]+)/'`), I get this output:

```
1_idle
6_mp3
Camera_snap
Camera_snap
Radio_202.16
```

Comment: Can you please help me out to write the full regular expression

Comment: But i am getting the error: Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation(.). I am using Windows7 platform. same your code i am using :(

Comment: Thanks Mark for quick help !!

Comment: you must have a typo, @user1362796. my code doesn't try to print out `$1` unless the regex matches, and there's no way the regex can match without setting `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $line = "MSM8939_BD_V4.3_1-1_idle-Kratos_Run3.xlsx";

for (qw(
    MSM8939_BD_V4.3_1-1_idle-Kratos_Run3.xlsx
    MSM8939_BD_V4.3_2-6_mp3-Kratos_Run2.xlsx
    MSM8939_BD_V4.3_Camera_snap-7.xlsx
    MSM8939_BD_V4.3_Camera_snap-8.xlsx
    MSM8939_BD_V4.3_Radio_202.16-0.xlsx
)) {
    my ($captured) = ($_ =~ /.*[-_]([^\W_]+_[\w.]+)-/gx);
    print "$captured\n";
}
```

Use a greedy pattern to go as far as possible, then grab the last two strings that look like what you want which are still followed by a hyphen.

As does the other answer which was just edited while I was typing, this produces:

```
1_idle
6_mp3
Camera_snap
Camera_snap
Radio_202.16
```

This one may be more general in that the beginning of the substring is not hard-coded, i.e., you could use it in other cases which did not necessarily start with `MSM8_BD_V4.3`.

Comment: Thanks Joseph for quick help !!

Comment: You're welcome! If you are running this on a lot of data, and realize later on for some reason that you need to match a different pattern that also shows up and you need to adapt the regexp to fit, feel free to ask again.